# Vote to merge "art" and "pictures" labels

Tags: discussion, tags, merge-tag-request

It seems (to me at least) that the "[art](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/art/info)" and "[pictures](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/pictures/info)" labels are redundant. Also, I wonder if even "[symbols-symbology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/symbols-symbology/info)" should also be absorbed, as well as terms such as "icon", "iconography", "depictions", etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of questions about sculptures under [art](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art) but none about dynamic art-forms, such as music or theater. I think that [pictures](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictures) should be synonimized into a new tag - `images`, which semantically includes both two-and three-dimensional images, and that this new tag should be applied to all of the questions currently bearing [art](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art) instead of it, since the word "art" can refer to all kinds of stuff not related to images.

[symbols-symbology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols-symbology), on the other hand, refers to all kinds of symbols, including purely conceptual ones. Some symbols are images and vice-versa, but these are different concepts. I think the tags should be distinct.